# Definition or Axiom for less than for real numbers

Tags: real-numbers, peano-axioms

I was curious as to what the definition for $<$ would be concerning real numbers. I have looked at Peanos axioms which discusses inequalities for every $a, b\in\mathbb{N}$, $a<b$ iff there is some $c\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a+c=b$. I am curious as to what it would be for real numbers. I could try to guess what it might be, but I am wanting to be exact. Any help or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Well that's all I needed lol. You are free to post in the answer box. Just curious if that axiom is called something. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, i made a mistake. We don't know what $c>0$ means (do we?).

Comment: I didn't catch that. Good point!

Comment: I don't know if you can get any more exact than that though.

Comment: The problem is fundamental. We can't define something via the same thing we're trying to define. Hence $a<b$ defined as $\exists c>0 : \ldots$ doesn't fly.

Comment: That sort of depends on how a real number is defined.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Okay. That makes sense. lol

Comment: A real number is defined with less than. Just trying to avoid circular reasoning on that note.

Comment: See [$\color{red}{\text{construction of a real number}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can define it as follows: $x\leq  y \iff (\exists z)(z^2 = y-x)$

Since someone voted to delete my answer, but did not leave a comment as to why this answer is incorrect, I will explain my answer more thoroughly.

My answer consider's the reals as a field in the ring language $\mathcal{L} =\{1,0,\times,+, -\}$. The reals as a field are naturally a structure in this language. My answer shows that $\leq$ is definable (in the model theory sense) in this structure in this particular language.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which definition of the real numbers you're using.

If you define real numbers as [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut), then each real number $x$ contains a set $A_x$ of rational numbers (which are intended to represent the rational numbers which are less than $x$). With this definition, the definition of $<$ is that $x < y$ whenever $A_x$ is a proper subset of $A_y$.

If you define real numbers as [equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences), then each real number $x$ is considered to be a class of Cauchy sequences $\{x_n\}$. With this definition, the definition of $<$ is that $x < y$ whenever, for all sufficiently large $n$, $x_n < y_n$, where the $<$ operator here is the one defined on the *rational* numbers. (But in order for this definition to be valid, it's necessary to prove that it gives the same answer regardless of *which* Cauchy sequence is chosen from each equivalence class.)

You can define the real numbers by specifying a list of axioms that they must obey and then proving that there is exactly one structure which satisfies all of the axioms. If you do this, then the meaning of $<$ is not explicitly defined; it's just specified by the axioms.

Finally, there's a definition of $<$ which is independent of the underlying definition. You can define $\le$ by saying that $x \le y$ whenever there is a number $z$ such that $z^2 = y - x$. Then you can say that $x < y$ whenever $x \le y$ and $x \ne y$; or, alternatively, you can say that $x < y$ whenever it is not the case that $y \le x$.

Comment: In undergrad, specifying the list of axioms is the go to method. The equivalence class definition seems odd. $x<y$ whenever for sufficiently large $n$, $x_n < y_n$. Is that a different $<$?

Comment: Yes, it is a different $<$ operator; it's the one defined on the rational numbers. I've edited this answer to make that clearer.

Comment: I like this answer more in the way that it has a lot of additional information in it. It is just that the other answer mentioned one particular idea first. I really do appreciate the effort put into answering this question. Thank you for that!

Comment: I really wish I could give points to multiple answers sometimes; it is something that bothers me with this site. Just wanted to let you know that I appreciate your help!